# jQuery mouseover, animate left or right while true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I want to move my overflowed div (calculated on window load) right or left depends on user's mouse position. (Continuous animation while mouse still there). I have some bugs / problems.

1. Move to the direction without stopping while mouse still over.
2. If i use animate function, this will work with start and stop over and over again causes bad animation.

Any ideas?

Note: i don't want to use any extra libraries except jquery.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var buildingsWrapper = $('#buildings'),
        lastBuilding = $('.building:last');

    buildingsWrapper.width(parseInt(lastBuilding.css('left')) + lastBuilding.width());

    var followMouseMove = function() {
        var animStarted = false;

        // ok now, mouse over but this will work for just one time.
        buildingsWrapper.on('mouseover', function(e) {
            if(e.clientX >= $(window).width() - 100) {
                var left = buildingsWrapper.css('left');

                if(!animStarted) {
                    animStarted = true;

                    // will work but will stop and start again after animStarted set to false. that start / stop is not what i want.
                    buildingsWrapper.animate({
                        left: parseInt(left) - 50
                    }, 300, function() {
                        animStarted = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };

    followMouseMove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mousemove:

```
buildingsWrapper.on('mouseover', function(){
     $(document).mousemove( function(e) {
            var mouseX = e.pageX;
            var slideT = (mouseX*(-1))+"px";



        buildingsWrapper.css({'left': slideT});
});     
        });
```

Try modifying slideT to get the animation you want

Comment: Not gonna work because user has to move his mouse to animate (go right or left).